# gdb - setting a breakpoint in a particular file in a binary

Tags: gdb

```
(gdb) b processMessage

No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.

Make breakpoint pending on future shared library load? (y or [n]) n

(gdb) file aqm_wfmgr

Reading symbols from /home/dir/bin/mgr...done.

(gdb) b processMessage
Function "processMessage" not defined.
```

How to set a breakpoint to a particular function @ some line no in a particular file of that  binary?

If I give direct line nos or func name and file nos, it doesnot recognize.please help.

```
(gdb) b 599

Cannot access memory at address 0x498f14

(gdb) b 598

Cannot access memory at address 0x498f14

(gdb) b processMessage 598

Function "processMessage" not defined.
```

Comment: break filename:filenumber actually works but it gives a error that 

    `(gdb) break FILE1.C:500
    No line 500 in file "FILE1.C"`.

But there is a line 500 in the actual code.

Comment: Have you tried setting a hardware breakpoint? See the "hbreak" command. Since the breakpoint will be on a memory address, no source file is needed; and since the memory address is stored in a debug register, there is no need to patch the binary with a trap instruction.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your binary is missing debug information. Make sure that you compile it with at least `-g` (assuming you are using gcc).

Comment: Iam compiling with the debug -g option only, still this issue.